# Convert a matrix of type "CV_32FC2" to type "CV_32FC1"

Tags: opencv

I have a matrix `a` of type `CV_32FC2`.

I tried to convert it into a new matrix `b` with type `CV_32FC1`, but seems that matrix `b` also gets `CV_32FC2`.

Code sample and output:

```
cv::Mat b;
a.convertTo(b, CV_32FC1);
std::cout << a.type() << " " << b.type() << std::endl;
```

Produces the output:

```
13 13
```

I expect the type of `b` to change to `5`, which is the enum value of `CV_32FC1`

Comment: In http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto it says *"rtype – desired output matrix type or, rather, the depth since the number of channels are the same as the input has;"*.

Comment: What do you mean under "convert", split channels, reshape or something else... ?

Comment: converTo converts the type (E.g. From float to uchar), not the number of channels. Use reshape: "b = a.reshape(1);"

Comment: use cv::split (mat,vectorOfMats)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a matrix `A` of type `CV_32FC2`, aka `Mat2f`:

```
Mat2f A(3,2);
randu(A, Scalar(0, 0), Scalar(1,1));
```

[image]

You can get a single matrix `B` of type `CV_32FC1`, aka `Mat1f` using [reshape](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#abca74fa43163dba52b70af4b48c69f62&gsc.tab=0):

```
Mat1f B = A.reshape(1);
```

[image]

Or two matrices `CV_32FC1` using [split](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga8027f9deee1e42716be8039e5863fbd9) (as suggested by @Micka in comments):

```
vector<Mat1f> CC;
split(A, CC);
```

where `CC[0]` is:

[image]

and `CC[1]` is:

[image]